# DataFrame: Setting all the values to a particular columns as NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF like

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G  H   I
=====================================
1   2   3       4   5   6   7   8
1   2   3       4   5   6   7   8
1   2   3       4   5   6   7   8
```

I need to set all the values for columns except for A and C to be Null

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G  H   I
=====================================
1       3
1       3
1       3
```

If there a way to do this instead of using the below code like using a not condition to check for only columns A & C and set null to every other columns

**df[['B','D','E','F','G','H','I']] = ''**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way could be to slice and reindex:

```
target = ['A', 'C']
out = df[target].reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

For in place modification you can take advantage of index difference:

```
df[df.columns.difference(target)] = float('nan')
```

output:

```
   A   B  C   D   E   F   G   H   I
0  1 NaN  3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  1 NaN  3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  1 NaN  3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

*NB. if you really want spaces as filling values:

```
# option 1:
out = df[target].reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value='')

# option 2:
df[df.columns.difference(target)] = ''

# output:
   A B  C D E F G H I
0  1    3            
1  1    3            
2  1    3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
target = ['A', 'C']
columns = [column for column in df.columns if column not in target]
df[columns] = float('nan')
```